# Weighted probability (dice divination)

Tags: probability, dice

Suppose you roll three 4-sided dice to arrive at one of 64 combinations.

Of these 64 combinations, 40 are "good," 15 are "bad," and 9 are "mixed."

You have to repeat the process three times, which makes for ten possible outcomes, e.g., 3 good; 2 good and 1 mixed; 2 good and 1 bad, etc. down to 3 bad.

What are the probabilities of each of the ten possible outcomes, given that one is more likely to receive a good combination (.625) versus a mixed (.14) or bad (.23) combination? What is the formula?

(In case you're wondering, this problem arises from a form of dice divination practiced in India and elsewhere with long dice called pashakas.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are ten combinations.  $\sf\{GGG,GGM,GGB,GMM,GMB,GBB,MMM,MMB,MBB,BBB\}$

The counts of good, mixed, and bad results among three trials will follow what is known as a *multinomial distribution*.

So the joint probability mass function is:$$\mathsf P(G{=}g, M{=}m, B{=}b) = \dfrac{3!}{g!~m!~b!}\frac{{40}^{\raise{0.5ex}g}{9}^{\raise{0.5ex}m}{15}^{\raise{0.5ex}b}}{64^3}~\mathbf 1_{g\geq 0, m\geq 0, b\geq 0,g+m+b=3}$$

Answer (score 1):

For each outcome (consisting of three fortunes) multiply the individual fortunes' probabilities together, and *then* multiply by the number of ways of permuting the fortunes. For example, the probability of getting one of each fortune (good, bad, mixed) is
$$6×\frac{40}{64}×\frac{15}{64}×\frac9{64}=\frac{2025}{16384}=0.1236$$
The probability of getting one bad and two good fortunes is
$$3×\frac{40}{64}×\frac{40}{64}×\frac{15}{64}=\frac{1125}{4096}=0.2747$$
The probability of getting three mixed fortunes is
$$1×\frac9{64}×\frac9{64}×\frac9{64}=\frac{729}{262144}=0.002781$$
The number of ways of permuting the fortunes is six in the good + bad + mixed case, one if all fortunes are the same and three otherwise.